# Application Level Network Sniffer

Tags: networking, packet-sniffers

Is there a better tool than **WireShark** to sniff out where given application is trying to connect and at which port. (So that I could easily overwrite it with my HOSTS file). Being able to log packet data is helpful too.

Ultimately I would prefer an application that I could just throw a running process at and start logging the network activities of the given app

Of course the application and sniffer will be running on the same PC. Preferably I would love a Windows sniffer. Since running that app on Linux will be .... difficult.

Answering myself: http://www.sysprobs.com/monitor-network-traffic-windows-7-microsoft-network-monitor-34
This article helped me big time. The tool in there is really great.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried socket sniff?

It should let you monitor specific applications:

[socket sniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/socket_sniffer.html)

Comment: It doesn't work. Keeps telling me that the application haven't initialized Socket.dll. I gave the program administrative priviledges, it still gave me the same error.